# Poincare invariant Lagrangian?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, poincare-symmetry

I only see it mentioned that we want Lorentz invariant Lagrangians in quantum field theory, but I would expect that we additionally also need translational invariance, i.e. Poincare invariance. After all we expect the laws of physics to be invariant under translation...

Am I mistaken to think we require the Lagragnian to exhibit Poincare invariance in QFT?

If yes, I would be very thankful if someone would be so kind as to elucidate why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not mistaken, but compared to Lorentz invariance, translation invariance is usually trivial because there are usually no fields with non-trivial behavior under translations - you have $\phi(x)\mapsto \phi(x+a)$ for a translation by $a$, but $\phi(x) \mapsto \rho(\Lambda)\phi(\Lambda x)$ under a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$, where $\rho(\Lambda) = 1$ only if $\phi$ is a scalar.

So in order to build a Lagrangian that's a Lorentz scalar you need to be a bit careful since you have fields that *aren't* scalars themselves, but they're all "scalars" with respect to translations and so there isn't really anything to pay attention to when trying to build a translation-invariant Lagrangian in the vast majority of cases.